# Video shooting in iPhone

Tags: iphone, video-capture, iphone-privateapi

Is there a way to capture video from iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Officially, no. Its not currently available via Apple, nor do they provide an API.

However if you Jailbreak the phone you can install unofficial applications that will let you do this. Or write your own of course!